# Auditing in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, auditing

We want / need to audit all statements on a number of tables in one of our instances.  So, we've enabled Unified Auditing.  That appears to be working.  We've created the policy, and we can see the DML & select statements in the UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL view.

However, what is missing appears the be the parameter values.   When we look at the SQL_TEXT column, we see:  SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = :"SYS_B_0"

Is there someplace, or some way we can see the parameter values in the SQL statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SQL_BINDS` column of the `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL` view contains the values of bind variables submitted with the query in the `SQL_TEXT` column.

```
SQL_TEXT                                                   SQL_BINDS
--------------------------------------------------------   ---------
SELECT "COL1","COL2 " FROM "TAB2" "T2" W HERE :1="COL1"    #1(1):3
```

Where `#1` refers to which bind variable, in order; `(1):` refers to the number of characters in the value; and `3` is the value.

This works with SQL that contains bind variables when submitted from the client, *and* with system-substituted bind variables like you are seeing such as `:"SYS_B_0"`.